# google chrome browser is differed from UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

google chrome browser is availabe in App store as a native application.

1)How will it be differed from safari?

2)How can it access device memory,have its all features if they have used
 UIWebview?Normal UIWebview is enough if they have used UIWebview.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome on iOS differs from Safari only in UI and ability to sync with Google services, cause it is based on Apple`s WebKit (rendering/layout engine)

Comment: Apple`s WebKit (rendering/layout engine) is differed from UIwebview?

Comment: UIWebView simply displays the website using webkit. It's in the documentation.

Comment: UIWebView uses WebKit to render pages, so it`s basically the same

Comment: how can google deliver normal UIWebview as google chrome browser?

Comment: They do not actually deliver a browser, they deliver a UIWebView with Chrome interface and functionality.

Comment: A rendering engine and an interface is pretty much the definition of a browser. Saying that it's "not actually a browser" because it's only a rendering engine and an interface doesn't make any sense. It's like saying that Safari isn't a browser because it's just WebKit with an interface.